# jquery show hide not working as intended

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have an effect that when a button is clicked the html/span will slide out. This work just fine. Then when I want users click outside of the button or html/span, the html/span will hide. The hide part is working too but when I tried the process again I have to double click the button just to show the slide effect. I suspect I have the order wrong or sth...can anyone help me?

```
$(document.body).ready(function () {

  $(".comment_function").on("click", function () {
      $(".comment_confirm").show(400,"linear");
  });

  $(document.body).on("click", function () {
      if (!$(".comment_function").closest(".comment_confirm").length) {
          if ($(".comment_confirm").is(":visible") ) {
              $(".comment_confirm").hide();
          }
      }
  });

});
```

dont know why the codes are not working in fiddle, but its very close to what I have now
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mnm47cb/)

Comment: use jsfiddel to show wht u r trying to do

Comment: You're running that second click handler every time someone clicks anything on the page... **ouch!** why not make it a `$.one()` and create it in the `comment_function` click handler

Comment: @saurav I have upload to fiddle but the codes are not working. It still very close to what I have now

Comment: @PatrickGunderson I am fairly new to jquery, sorry about that :( what you mean by make it a     $.one() ?

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/5mnm47cb/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just listen for click events in from `document` and check whether the element clicked is `.one`. If yes, show `.two` otherwise hide it.

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
  var t = $(e.target);
  if (t.hasClass('one')) {
    $('.two').show(400, 'linear');
  } else {
    $('.two').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks :), As you answer what I wanted it first I will upvote yours :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I came up with : used "events" object's target property to obtain click -

```
$(document).bind("click", function (e) {
  var clickedElement = $(e.target);
    console.log($(e.target));
    if (clickedElement.hasClass('one') || clickedElement.hasClass('two')) {
      console.log("one");
    $('.two').show(400, 'linear');
  } else {
      console.log("two");
    $('.two').hide();
  }
  });
```

Works as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/5mnm47cb/12/

Answer (score 1):

I have just able too get the single click enabled.
You should try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on("click", function (e) {
      if (!$(".comment_function").closest(".comment_confirm").length) {
          if ($(".comment_confirm").is(":visible") ) {
              $(".comment_confirm").hide();
          }
      }
   });

   if($(e.target).is('.comment_function'))
       $(".comment_confirm").show();
});
```

Here is working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/sda33ysb/1/)